# Suggest performance improvement for rotation of array with given no of steps of rotation

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-8, bufferedreader

I am solving a problem on hacker-earth which is about the *right shifting* of an integer array with `x` steps of rotation. Given below is sample input,output:

Input:
testcases -- 1
[No of elements in array, Steps of rotation] -- 5 2
[Elements in array] -- 1 2 3 4 5

Output:
`4 5 1 2 3`

The whole problem statement is available on internet with title - *Monk and Rotation*

So, My code is working fine for 5 testcases but fails for 1 with exceeded time limit. I tried changing the `scanner` class & used `bufferedreader` & input stream reader for faster input reading still no luck. Below is the code, please suggest what improvements can be done.

```java
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    
    class TestClass {
        public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    
            int noOfElements,stepsOfRotation;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int testCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());        
            while(testCases!=0)
            {
                String firstLine=br.readLine();
                String[] parts=firstLine.split(" ");
    
                noOfElements=Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                stepsOfRotation=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    
                int[] arr=new int[noOfElements];
                
                String secondLine=br.readLine();
                String[] arrayElements=secondLine.split(" ");
    
             for(int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++)
                {
                arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(arrayElements[i]);
                }
    
            stepsOfRotation %= noOfElements;  
    
            int result;
            for(int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++)
            {
                result=arr[(i+(noOfElements-stepsOfRotation))%noOfElements];
                System.out.print(result+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            testCases--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you start using `StringTokenizer` for array inputs and `StringBuilder` for printing the output for all such coding problems.
Here we have a large dataset as input and output so it's always recommendable to use the above as more the number of `print` calls, slower would be your program.
Declaration:

```java
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
```

And instead of printing each element, append them to the StringBuilder `sb`.

```java
            for(int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++)
            {
                result=arr[(i+(noOfElements-stepsOfRotation))%noOfElements];
                sb.append(result).append(" ");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
            testCases--;
        }
        System.out.print(sb);
```

Please read about `StringTokenizer` if you don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Should the last `p` not be `result`?
Please let the IDE format the code. And declare variables as close as possible to the first usage.

The code itself is alright, though slightly costly is `split`.

One could do without String array:

```
     int pos = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<noOfElements; i++) {
         int pos2 = firstLine.indexOf(' ', pos);
         if (pos2 == -1) {
             pos2 = firstLine.length();
         }
         arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(firstLine.substring(pos, pos2);
         pos = pos2 + 1;
     }
```